# Ros1 to ros2 bridge a specific topics

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Is there any way to bridge a specific topic

Like I'm using a kinect camera to generate a laser scan data

When I run the bridge there are a big delay in the laser scan data
Close to 1 fps

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405068/ros1-to-ros2-bridge-a-specific-topics/) by [iimata](https://answers.ros.org/users/101281/iimata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2022-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most direct way would be to use the parameter_bridge instead of the dynamic_bridge
https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge#example-4-bridge-only-selected-topics-and-services

The above instructions ^ will work with the ros1_bridge provided by your ROS distribution.

In my own work, I found the separation of the two to be a bit limiting and instead manually combined the parameter_bridge and dynamic_bridge in my team's fork. https://github.com/usdot-fhwa-stol/ros1_bridge (ROS2 foxy). Launched with

```
rosparam load bridge.yml && source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash && ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge
```

To use my fork you would need to compile it following the ros1_bridge instructions. The bridge.yml file takes precedence over the dynamic behavior.

---

Originally posted by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) with karma: 268 on 2022-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iimata](https://answers.ros.org/users/101281/iimata/) on 2022-08-16**:
first, thank u bro for you help

- i tried to bridge my laserscanner
  data and i got this error

  [INFO] [1660674982.068587236]
  [ros_bridge]: create bidirectional
  bridge for topic /depth_scan

  failed to create bidirectional bridge
  for topic '/depth_scan' with ROS 2
  type 'sensor_msgs/LaserScan': No
  template specialization for the pair

  Trying to create bridge for ROS 2
  service
  '/depthimage_to_laserscan/get_loggers'
  with type 'roscpp/GetLoggers'

  failed to create bridge ROS 1 service
  '/depthimage_to_laserscan/get_loggers'
  no conversion for type
  'roscpp/GetLoggers'

  Trying to create bridge for ROS 1
  service '/add_two_ints' with type
  'example_interfaces/srv/AddTwoInts'

  failed to create bridge ROS 2 service
  '/add_two_ints' no conversion for
  type
  'example_interfaces/srv/AddTwoInts'

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-16**:
@mh-ta: I wonder if you need to compile your IDL files with `ros1_bridge` first. I have found the `ros1_bridge` working all right this way.

**Comment by [iimata](https://answers.ros.org/users/101281/iimata/) on 2022-08-17**:
its work fine bro ..
but im using kinect camera to generate a laser scan data,
the camera launch file generates alot of topics that i dont need such as(/camera/depth/image_raw)which it has a heavy data to bridge, and it is making alot of lag

**Comment by [iimata](https://answers.ros.org/users/101281/iimata/) on 2022-08-17**:
i solved the problem, i wrote the ros1 type topic it has to be a ros2 type